# Deleting a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I've been trying to delete a doubly linked list, but it doesn't work when I test it. I think it doesn't work when I have one node. Front and end are part of a node, front pointing to previous and end pointing to the next node. Could someone help me?

```
doublylinkedlist::~dlinkedl() 
{
this->front = NULL;
this->size = 0;
this->end = this->front;
}
```

Comment: Where are you trying to delete in the code? Browse through [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/delete-a-node-in-a-doubly-linked-list/) link so that you may get a good idea about deleting a node in a doubly linked list.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I want to delete all the nodes.